# How to register a broadcast on QGIS to start my plugin on start after loading plugins

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I want to perform a default task when user opens QGIS but here I am building it as a python plugin so I want a signal or broadcast to call my plugin.

1. I didn't build QGIS from source
2. my plugin should be called when QGIS finish loading plugins on start

can anyone help with the documentation I can refer about the broadcasts and calls i can register to.

how should I approach my problem?
I have found a help on startup.py but it seems to help run python not run plugins.but tried using it and keep bugging errors like

```
Couldn't load qgis.user.
```

Python support will be disabled.

Now my plugin is python/plugin/Loadmap folder in side it there is a file LoadMap.py and I want to run the run method inside it.

Answer (score 2):

in your plugin **init**() you can add a listener to `iface.initializationCompleted` signal

http://qgis.org/api/classQgisInterface.html#a6f1cc8be7d4e0b4c76c2806b78b3d8b0

then do what you want

regards